# Definition of Subspace

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces

The definition of a subspace is 
Let $K$ be a field , $V$ be a vector space over $K$(such as the real numbers), and let $W$ be a subset of $V$. Then $W$ is a subspace if
1.)The zero vector, $\textbf0$, is in $W$.
2.)If $\textbf u$ and $\textbf v$ are elements of W, then the sum $\textbf u + \textbf v $ is an element of $W$.
3.)If $\textbf u$ is an element of $W$ and $c$ is a scalar from $K$, then the scalar product $c\textbf u$ is an element of $W$.

Isn't the first condition redundant? If the second and third conditions are satisfied then we have,
$$-(1)\cdot\textbf{u}=-\textbf u \in W$$
Since
$$-1 \in K$$
Thus
$$\textbf u+(-\textbf u)=\textbf 0 \in W$$

Comment: The first condition ensures that $W$ is not empty. (So it is equivalent to say $W\ne \emptyset$)

Comment: Ohk, thank you very much!